# If the value of the array at the index agrees with if, I want to add it to "array" at 0 and then 1 and so on. I'm running into issues here

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to add b[i] to array[0] and array[1] and so on if it > x or < y...this currently adds them incorrectly.

```
public int[] method(int[] b, int x, int y) {


array = new int[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

     if (b[i] > x && b[i] < y) { 
        int r = 0;
        array[r] = b[i];   
        r++; 
     }
  }
```

Comment: You'll get better responses here if you state exactly what your issues are / what is incorrect.

Comment: What does >x or <y means ?

Comment: what is the problem you found on the code, write clear with reuirements

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `r` each time, so you'll always add it in spot 0. Try this instead, where the declaration is moved out.

```
array = new int[10];
int r = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

 if (b[i] > x && b[i] < y) { 

    array[r] = b[i];   
    r++; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `r` outside the `loop` because each time `loop` executes it set the value of `r` to `0`
Do Something like that

```
array = new int[10];
     int r = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
     if (b[i] > x && b[i] < y) { 
        array[r] = b[i];   
        r++; 
     }
  }
```